# How to drag and update location icon in Google map using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-web-api

I am displaying Google maps now by search location by textbox.  It's working fine.  Now what I want is to drag the location icon from the map to a different location and to update location with the help of button.

I am trying to find a function or API call for this, but I'm still struggling with this code.

This is my current working code :

```
  function loadMaps() {
  var address = $("#txtAddress").val()

  var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  geo.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var myLatLngh = results[0].geometry.location;

                    var myOptions = {
                        center: myLatLngh,
                        zoom: 12,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
                        }

                    };

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLngh,
                        title: address
                    });

                    marker.setMap(map);
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>Location Address</b><br/> " + address });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

 } 
        else {

        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to enable the `draggable` option on your marker first:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLngh,
    title: address,
    draggable: true
});
```

You can then use `marker.getPosition().lat()` and `marker.getPosition().lng()` in a callback. Something like this using the `dragend` event:

```
marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
    // Do something with the positions here
    // once the user has finished dragging the marker
    console.log(marker.getPosition().lat());
    console.log(marker.getPosition().lng()); 
});
```

Here is a **[basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273326/google-maps-api-v3-event-listener-on-a-class/32276546#32276546)**