# Google Maps API V3 : event listener on a class

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

It is possible to detect an event with Google Maps V3 API, for instance (ex 1) :

```
 google.maps.event.addListener('drag', function(event) { 
            $("#latD").val(event.latLng.lat()); 
            $("#longD").val(event.latLng.lng()); 
        });
```

or (ex 2)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerDep, 'drag', function(event) { 
        $("#latD").val(event.latLng.lat()); 
        $("#longD").val(event.latLng.lng()); 
    });
```

here, I specified an instance of a Marker.

According to Google Maps API Specification, one can create a listener on a particular event (example 1), and even create a listener for a particular event on a particular instance (example 2).

But is it possible to detect the same event for all the instances of a same class? For instance, can I detect a "dragend" event on all the instances of Marker?

Comment: Could your reference where in the documentation you got those examples from?  Neither of them makes sense to me as written in your question.

Comment: I updated the code above. I think the answer to my question is "no, you can't". I probably must add a listener to every instance of Marker...

Comment: The examples now make more sense, but I still don't know where the first example comes from.  All the [MapsEventListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapsEventListener) functions take an instance as the first argument.

Comment: They came from a previous code I made, which was wrong, I made a mistake between my 2 Notepad++ windows, I'm sorry. Yes that is what I figured, thanks anyway. I have to create as listeners as there exist instances of Marker

Answer (score 0):

If you have got multiple markers and are trying to create an event for each each marker, in this case the `dragend` event, you would need to include it in the `for` loop which generates your markers.

The snippet below assumes you are trying to get the longitude and latitude of a marker after it has been dragged. These values get inserted into the input boxes below the map.

```css
#map {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<input id="latD" type="text">
<input id="longD" type="text">

<script>
// The following map creates complex markers to indicate destinations
// Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond to the base of the iamge.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    center: {lat: -2.75181, lng: 24.11768}
  });

    setMarkers(map);
  }

  // Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
  // order in which these markers should display on top of each other
  var destinations = [
    ['Congo', -2.72760, 23.52084, 1],
    ['South Africa', -33.58880, 20.07114, 1],
    ['Brazil', -6.26352, -57.38128, 1]
  ];

  function setMarkers(map) {
    // Adds markers to the map.

    // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
    // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

    // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
    // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
    var image = {
      url: 'http://i.imgur.com/OG4CZt3.png',
      // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is just off centre (0, 10).
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 10)
    };
    // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
    // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
    // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
    var shape = {
      coords: [1, 1, 1, 32, 30, 32, 30, 1],
      type: 'poly'
    };
    
    for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
      var destination = destinations[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: destination[1], lng: destination[2]},
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          icon: image,
          shape: shape,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          title: destination[0],
          zIndex: destination[3],
      });

      marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
          jQuery("#latD").val(this.getPosition().lat()); 
          jQuery("#longD").val(this.getPosition().lng()); 
      });
    }
}
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**More information** [**in the docs**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)